# Setting radio button boostrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to set a bootstrap radio button with Jquery:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("input[value='female']").prop('checked', true);
}, 1000);
```

Unfortunately it only seems to work when I remove data-toggle="buttons". Please take a look at the jsfiddle. It works for the second row of radio buttons but not for the first row. Any idea how I can get it to work for the first row too?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9180/)

Comment: is data-toggle necessary then?

Comment: I prefer the look of the first row of radio buttons...

Comment: @Balachandran not sure what you mean... you have only changed female by male as far as I can see. The question is how to programmatically check one (any) of the buttons of the first row of buttons. The timeout is just to make the effect more obvious in jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9183/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".btn.btn-default:nth-child(1)").find("input").prop('checked', true).end().addClass("active");
}, 1000);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9184/)**

Comment: Super, thanks. Looks like the key takeaway is that the label needs a class 'active' to appear pressed...

Answer (score 1):

You can Manually override the toggle effect by adding a `active` class to the label containing the respective radio button.

**JS CODE:**

```
setTimeout(function () {
 $("input[value='female']").prop('checked', true);
 $("input[type='radio']").parent().removeClass('active');
 $("input[value='female']").parent().addClass('active');
}, 1000);
```

**Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/DTcHh/9185/**

This trick was already mentioned in [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio).

**From Bootstrap :**
*Visual checked state only updated on click
If the checked state of a checkbox button is updated without firing a click event on the button (e.g. via  or via setting the checked property of the input), you will need to toggle the .active class on the input's label yourself.*

Answer (score 0):

What about to remove the data-toggle first then change the checkbox and then add it again?

```
setTimeout(function () {
      $("input[value='female']").removeAttr('data-toggle');
      $("input[value='female']").prop('checked', true);
      $("input[value='female']").attr('data-toggle', true);
 }, 1000);
```